# unable to set toggle button on right most side of list view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i  used list view in my android app. i used toggle button in my listview. i want to set the toggle button at right corner of listview. but i am unable to do the same. so please help me out.... the code snippet of my xml file are here......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/aaa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"

            android:src="@drawable/rihanna" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <!-- Name Label -->





       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/email"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:paddingBottom="2dip"
           android:paddingTop="5dp"
           android:textColor="#acacac" />






    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="right"




        android:background="@drawable/toggle"
        android:text=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:focusable="false">
    </ToggleButton>
    </LinearLayout>
 <!--
       <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/arrow"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
           /> -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, will you try layout_gravity="end"; layout_gravity="right";?

Comment: @Sheychan yes i tried it. but this is not working for me.

Comment: ok, what do you mean by corner right? top-right or bottom right?

Comment: i want  to add toggle in every list item  at right corner

Comment: I see, if you want to persist on linearlayout lemme build an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/aaa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"

            android:src="@drawable/rihanna" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <!-- Name Label -->





       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/email"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:paddingBottom="2dip"
           android:paddingTop="5dp"
           android:textColor="#acacac" />






    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_gravity="right"




        android:background="@drawable/toggle"
        android:text=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:focusable="false">
    </ToggleButton>
    </LinearLayout>
 <!--
       <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/arrow"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
           /> -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this. I have added android:layout_weight="1" to the layout and 
    android:layout_gravity="right" for toggle button.

Comment: this is working for me but i can't got proper view. by using it i got toggle button at right .but my list item is also move ahead at right side

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft
```

and

```
android:layout_alignParentRight
```

are not the properties of **LinearLayout**.You have to use **RelativeLayout** for that.Here see the changes i've made in your xml so that the radio button comes in Right.(change the drawables back acc to your req as this is a demo)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/aaa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:background="@drawable/abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <!-- Name Label -->


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#acacac" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="right">

        </LinearLayout>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
            android:focusable="false">
        </ToggleButton>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/aaa"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/aaa" />
    <!--
          <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/arrow"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
              /> -->

</RelativeLayout>
```